# Derivative of integral(University Math problem)

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> If $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \int_0^{f(x)} \sin(t^2) \, \mathrm d t = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \sin (x)$$ find $f(x)$.

Okay, so I have $\sin(f(x)^2) * f'(x) = (1/2)  x^{-1/2} \sin (x)$

I figured that $f(x) = x^{1/2}$

I do not know how to formally show this can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put 
$$G(y):=\int_0^y\sin(t^2)\>dt\qquad(-\infty<y<\infty)\ .$$
Then $G$ is strictly increasing in the interval $J:=\bigl[-\sqrt{\pi},\sqrt{\pi}\bigr]$, hence $G\restriction J$ has an inverse $G^{-1}$ defined in some interval $J':=[-\rho,\rho]$. Furthermore
$${d\over dx}G\bigl(\sqrt{x}\bigr)={\sin x\over 2\sqrt{x}}\qquad(x\geq0)\ .$$
We are therefore given that
$${d\over dx}G\bigl(f(x)\bigr)={d\over dx}G\bigl(\sqrt{x}\bigr)\qquad(x\geq0)\ ,$$
or at least in some reasonable $x$-interval. This implies
$$G\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=G\bigl(\sqrt{x}\bigr)+c$$
for some real constant $c:=G\bigl(f(0)\bigr)$. If $x$ and $c$ are small enough to guarantee $G\bigl(\sqrt{x}\bigr)+c\in J'$ we can apply $G^{-1}$ on both sides and obtain
$$f(x)=G^{-1}\bigl(G(\sqrt{x})+c\bigr)\ .$$
In particular, if $f(0)=0$, we obtain the solution $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, valid for all $x\geq0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Edit: Let $f$ be continuous then;

$$\int_{0}^{x^2} f(t) \ dt$$

exists. By $FTC$ there exists a function $F$ with $F' = f$ and;

$$ \int_{0}^{x^2} f(t) \ dt = F(x^2) - F(0) \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x^2} f(t) \ dt = F'(x^2) \cdot 2x = 2x \cdot f(x^2)$$

Comment: I know that but I don't know how.

Comment: @Faraad Armwood: In your last conclusion, you miss the term $x^2$ in $F'(x)$ and $f(x)$, i.e. it should be $F'(x^2)$ and $f(x^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\sin(t^2)$ is continuous, hence the integral exists and there is an anti-derivative of the integrand, say $G(t)$, even though you're not able to write it down explicitely (assuming that $f$ is a continuous function as well). Hence $\int \limits_0^{f(x)} \sin(t^2) \ \mathrm{d}t = G(f(x)^2) - G(0)$; The derivative of the right-hand side of this equation evaluates to $\sin(f(x)^2) \cdot 2 f(x) \cdot f'(x)$, and this shall be equal to $\frac{\sin(x)}{2 \sqrt{x}}$...are you able to continue from here?